# "Extirpation" vs "Perdition" vs "Smash"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

I am a bit confused, how can I use these three words differently when their meaning is almost the same?

> - *Extirpation*
> - *Perdition*
> - *Smash*

Comment: I don't think this is a meaningful question at all. Anyone who thinks these words are "almost same" would be well advised to simply avoid using the first two completely.

Comment: Why do you think that this is a meaningful question ?I posted it here after searching on google , and google shows the same meaning for these words.

Comment: My apologies if I seem unduly dismissive. But I just Googled **define xxxx** for each, and nothing in each first page of results mentioned either of the other two words. I've no doubt that if I looked them all up in a single dictionary (online or printed), I wouldn't find much similarity in the definitions. And I think this site is more about seeking *subtle* differences in meaning and usage that might not easily be discovered by consulting a dictionary. In this case I stand by my original advice that you should simply avoid the first two at this stage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The meanings are certainly not the same, nor even “almost” the same. *perdition* is the most peculiar of the three, meaning “damnation”, “hell” or “doom”. It is a name, with no corresponding verb.

*Extirpate* is a verb, completely synonymous with *eradicate*; it implies complete destruction.

*Smash*, like *demolish*, implies complete wreckage, breaking into pieces, shattering (in addition to *demolish*, *smash* has the idea of violence).

---

Regarding usage, *smash* is very widely used, though not specifically informal. The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* has 1972 hits, while it has 168 for *perdition* (mainly in fiction and in academic theological works) and 59 for *extirpate*.

Comment: Also, you don't hear “The building at Fifth and Elm was smashed by the earthquake.” Usually little things get *smashed*, like birds’ nests, china dishes, bifocals, and sensitive electronic equipment. They *are smashed by* larger, heavier things. To me, *smash* doesn't quite imply *complete* wreckage, just enough that the object is pretty much ruined.

Comment: I'd also say that the words are used in rather different contexts.  'Smash' is rather colloquial and will be used on the street.  You'll hear 'perdition' (which I translate as 'loss') used mostly in a religious context.  And you'll rarely hear 'extirpate' at all.  It's a fine word, but rare enough that it might not be understood by many audiences.

Comment: Smash does not imply complete wreckage. I can smash my fist into the table but neither are destroyed in the process. It just hurts a lot. Smash, in my opinion, can be described as the violent collision of two or more objects. When I smash a table apart I am often using another object to do so (such as a floor, the wall or a sledgehammer.) If I tore the parts of a table asunder it would hardly qualify as "smashing" the table.

Comment: 'Smash' also has a positive context, as in "That record was a *smash* hit."

Answer (score 4):

These words have very little in common.

*Perdition* comes from the Latin word for "lost" and usually means "hell".

*Extirpation* is a form of the verb "to extirpate". It literally means "to uproot" and is usually used to express removing all traces of something. E.g. "extirpate all mentions of the executed officials name from the textbooks".

*Smash* simply means to break something into little pieces.

Answer (score 1):

*Extirpation* (as answered by) many comes from the verb extripate meaning root out completely.
The synonym closest is to eradicate. In fact the root of the word extirpate is sometimes said to come from eradicate itself. Extirpate is usually associated with social ills: *extirpate untouchability*, *extirpate anti-semitism*, *extirpate plague*, etc.

*Smash* has got more to do with collision, like two cars smashed, etc. It may not result in eradication of the two cars.

*Perdition* comes from a root meaning destruction. The closest meaning would be Hell. You can say *the road to perdition*, *suffer in perdition*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Extirpation is a form of the verb "to extirpate". It literally means "to uproot" and is usually used to express removing all traces of something. E.g. "extirpate all mentions of the executed officials name from the textbooks".